# if statement on select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form which has a yes or no select form

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
    <%= f.select :happy, ['Yes', 'No'], {}, :class => 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>
```

model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  has_many :posts
end
```

routes:

```
devise_for :users
```

I want to put a condition in the model to check if the user selected 'yes'. I have tried something like this, but it does not work?:

```
if self.happy = "yes"
  do something here
end
```

how could I check if the user selected yes or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so guessing that happy is a `string`? I would say your solution, with the **double equa**l sign, should work.

If it's a `boolean`, as it should be, I believe you could do something like:

```
<%= f.select :happy, [['Yes', true], ['No', false]], {}, :class => 'form-control' %>
```

Now I'm half paranoid that it will be interpreted as a `string`, if so, you might have to do some controller checks, using **double equal** sign.

#### EDIT

Just checked and my solution worked for me using a `boolean`.

If you wanted, you could go and build presenters, decorators that enable this functionality across your application as a whole.

Kind of what MVVM tries to accomplish, reducing the amount of transition and glue code required.

#### EDIT 2

I would strongly recommend using a `boolean` for yes/no data, since it can be represented with true/false. Storing a `string`, then doing checks also means `.downcase`ing or `.upcase`ing the `string` to ensure the check passes when it should.

If you're saving data from your `select_tag` (i.e `"Yes"`) without converting then checking if `happy == "yes"` will be `false`.

Using a `boolean` completely eliminates that problem.

```
thing.update(thing_params)

if.happy?
  do something here
end
```

Comment: happy is not a string, its a column in the user table which i added

Comment: @user5724342 whats the datatype of happy column in db ?

Comment: datatype is string

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected values from the form in your `params`

If your form looks like the following:

```
<%= form_for @resource do |f| %>
 <%= f.select :happy, ['Yes', 'No'], {}, :class => 'form-control' %>
<% end %>
```

Then you can get the selected value in your controller as follows:

```
if params[:resource][:happy] == 'Yes'
   do something....
end
```

If you like to do certain operation in your model, then you can simply call a method of you model and pass the `params` values as an argument and do the rest of work.

Comment: Im trying to implement this in a User model could you give the example which could be implemented into the user model, I'm new to rails so finding it hard to understand the logic behind it

Comment: Yes sure. Can you please update your question with complete form, UsersController and what exactly you want to do in your User model ? I assume you have **resources :users** specified in your **routes.rb**.

Comment: @user5724342   Is **happy** a column in your **posts** table ? How are you rendering the above form i.e from which controller and action ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume user should be happy or not happy about posts. (And you have form for post too, not for user.)

So you should store happy status not in users table but in posts table. Otherwise it will be rewritten every time user submit new post.
Else if you want to store only last happy status inside user model you should use PostsController to collect happy field and manually save it to user model.

The best approach anyway is to store all happy statuses in posts table and select only last one. So the history of happy statuses will be complete and you allways can associate happy status with appropriate post.

Your user model implementation should look like:

```
# determine if user was happy last time he submitted new post
def happy?
    # getting last post, assume it has created_at field
    last_post = self.posts.order("created_at").last

    # return true if user was happy 
    last_post.happy == "yes"
end

...
# and use it anywhere inside model

if self.happy?
    # do something
end
```

You may want to check happy values in users table. If values is saved successfully, and you don't want to store happy status in posts table just correct string comparison operator, use:

```
if self.happy == "yes"
    # do something
end
```

Answer (score 0):

attr_accessor :happy

if self.happy == "yes"

do something

else

do something

end